# facebook application for login and messenger same ids?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-messenger-bot

I am building a facebook messenger bot. And the bot is giving user ids. But it is not clear to me if the messenger ids are the same ids that would be returned if I use the same app and add to it a login feature. Because we already have an app and has a login feature, now we need to build a facebook bot and identify the already existing users in our db that are using the bot.

I have read facebook tutorial about linking 2 different applications to the same business to get consistent ids. But what if I use that same application to login users AND for messengers (by using the add products to the application, and so having one application, one app id) would that work? Would I be getting the same user ids?

PS: I would test myself but I am in an awkward position where the page/database/login app owner is a different person, and they are not big on sharing data, and I am supposed to blindly write a messenger code that is supposed to work when they deploy it.

All help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The only thing you can do without a business, is use Account Linking to make the users log in to your app, upon which you get their app-scoped user id, which you can then “connect” with the page-scoped id you got from messenger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Facebook's ID Matching APIs for this purpose:

Here is the details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/id-matching

Comment: I am afraid no.